# Python Update random field choice function from OrderedDict Class

Tags: python, string, function

I'm trying to do a script that choose a string and update a current field, but for some reason the code doesn't update the last value when calling my `changerandom` function in the `Greeting` class.

```
...[snip]...
class Greeting(Packet):
    fields = OrderedDict([
         ("Morning",     "Hi"),
         ("Afternoon",   "Good Afternoon!"),
         ("Evening",     "Good Evening!"),
    ])

    def change(self):
        self.fields["Morning"] = "Good morning!"

    def changerandom(self, n = 1): 
        function=[
                    {self.fields["Morning"]: "Hello!"},
                    {self.fields["Morning"]: "Bonjorno!"},
                    {self.fields["Morning"]: "Hola!"},
                 ]
        result = {}
        for i in range(n):
            result.update(choice(function))
            print "Updated string:",result
            return result
text = Greeting()
print text
text.change()
print text
text.changerandom()
print text
```

My code return the following:

```
Hi
Good morning!
Updated string: {'Good morning!': 'Hola!'}
Good morning!
```

While it should have returned:

```
Hi
Good morning!
Hola!
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing here, I don't see why I cannot update the last field. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're `return`ing a result, without assigning it anywhere.

You also use the *value* of `fields`, rather than the *key*.  So, your code should be something like

```
def changerandom(self, n = 1): 
        function=[
                    {"Morning": "Hello!"},
                    {"Morning": "Bonjorno!"},
                    {"Morning": "Hola!"},
                 ]

        for i in range(n):
            result = choice(function)
            self.fields.update(result)
            print "Updated string:",result
            return result
```

Note that we're using `self.fields.update`, and we're no longer `return`ing anything.

Generally, it's good practice for your functions and methods to *return* something, or *change something*, but never both.